# Blinking Frame on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a bunch of Autoplay looping Vimeo embedded on my site working fine on Chrome and Firefox but somehow i get a blinking frame while using Safari 12.0
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Here’s a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ta_io/pen/EzwQOr)

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
    <div id="made-in-ny">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/334777402?background=1&byline=0&portrait=0&autopause=0&color=ddd&title=0&autoplay=1&loop=1;transparent=0&amp;gesture=media" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
        allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you have allowfullscreen twice in your iframe ? (it's both at the start and the end)?

Comment: no, it's just an error, but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my site, did you ever figure this out?